# Rabbit MQ Fanout Setup With Lowest Latency in Java

Tags: java, performance, rabbitmq, low-latency

I am playing around with RabbitMQ in Java to try and see what latencies I can expect when publishing messages to a fanout exchange and having a couple of consumers, all of which are running on the same machine.

The way I am measuring the latency is by simply encoding a timestamp in the message right before invoking `channel.basicPublish()` Then when I receive the msg on the other side, I take another timestamp and compute the diff between the 2. Right now I am seeing latencies that are in the 2 to 4 ms range.

I would like to configure my exchange and queues to offer the least reliability guarantees, and hopefully minimize latency in the process (no persistence, no ack, no guaranteed delivery, etc). I am having a hard time finding all of these settings. In particular when it comes to not having acks, nor persistence.

Could anyone help settings things up to minimize latency as much as possible? And overall would someone know what best latencies I could achieve when dealing with consumers and producers all on the same machine? Would sub 100us be achievable?

Here is my code so far:

```java
import com.rabbitmq.client.*;
import java.time.Instant;

class SPMCPublisher2 {

    private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "logs";

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        try (Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
             Channel channel = connection.createChannel()) {
             channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "fanout");

            long count = 0;
            while (true) {
                final Instant now = Instant.now();
                final long now_ts = now.toEpochMilli() * 1000 + now.getNano()/1000;
                final String message = "msg #" + (++count) + "," + now_ts;
                channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, "",
                        new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder()
                                .contentType("text/plain")
                                .build(),
                        message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

                System.out.println(" --> '" + message + "'");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }

}


class SPMCConsumer11 {
    private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "logs";
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "my_queue";
    private static final boolean AUTO_ACK = true;
    private static final boolean NOT_DURABLE = false;

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "fanout");
        //on-durable, exclusive, autodelete queue with a generated name
        channel.queueDeclareNoWait(QUEUE_NAME,NOT_DURABLE, true, true ,null);
        channel.queueBind(QUEUE_NAME, EXCHANGE_NAME, "");

        DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
            final String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
            final Instant now = Instant.now();
            final long now_ts = now.toEpochMilli() * 1000 + now.getNano()/1000;
            final String[] parts = message.split(",");
            final long latency_us = now_ts - Long.parseLong(parts[1]);
            System.out.println(" <-- '" + message + "', latency: " + latency_us + " us");

        };
        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, AUTO_ACK, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });
    }
}
```

Comment: Classical messaging brokers weren't designed for  min latency possible. Especially RabbitMQ. To have significantly optimized latency for your specific case (no persistence, no ack, no guaranteed delivery, etc), you'd better use something like REDIS pub-sub or even better  https://github.com/real-logic/aeron

Comment: Very nice @AnatolyG, definitely seems like I was looking at the wrong solution!